# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext classpath notfound

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, classpath

I am newbie in Spring. I have problem with classpath as parameter of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`. I use Netbeans. The class where I use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is in package `cz.ryska.helloworld` in Source Packages folder. Configuration XML file, name as Beans.xml is in WEB-INF folder.

[image]

But I don't know what way I can use. I try use f.e "WEB-INF\Beans.xml" or "/WEB-INF/Beans.xml" but file is not found. What way I can use or where I must move xml file? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The project appears to be a J2EE web application, so you shouldn't need to create a new DI container with `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`.  Instead import `beans.xml` in your `applicationContext.xml` file, if it is already registered in web.xml.

**In web.xml include:**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**In applicationContext.xml include:**

```
<import resource="Beans.xml"/>
```

This will cause the `Beans.xml` configuration to be added to the DI container.